# How to sort buckets by doc_count?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

```
GET /civile/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "distretto": "MI"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "our_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          { "codiceoggetto": { "terms": { "field": "codiceoggetto.keyword", "order": "desc" } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Elasticsearch query match documents by distretto = "MI".
With size = 0 I hide results.

But most important thing is that I define our_buckets aggregation.
It return 1000 keys and it do a "group by" on codiceoggetto.keyword field.

Now I want order my buckets results by doc_count! How can I do?

Here the response

```
{
  "took" : 20,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "our_buckets" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "codiceoggetto" : "010001"
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "codiceoggetto" : "490999"
          },
          "doc_count" : 3
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "codiceoggetto" : "481312"
          },
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using [bucket_sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "distretto": "MI"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "our_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 1000,
        "sources": [
          {
            "codiceoggetto": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "codiceoggetto.keyword",
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sort_by_count": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_count": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, today I test your query but it doesn't work. I get `"type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Unknown aggregation type [sort_by_count]"`. How can I solve it?

Comment: I have used doc_count as sort field but the error changes in `named_object_not_found_exception`

Comment: could you please share your mappings and sample data along with query you tried? I can look into it

Comment: In this moment I can't share data and schema mapping. Sorry.